# How do I force an Eclipse plug-in to be unpacked?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

My eclipse plug-in must be unpacked.

How can I enforce the installer to unpack it?

Will it be unpacked if the jar file is simply dropped into the `plugins` folder?

Comment: why does it need to be unpacked? (if you're opening files at runtime, you can use getResourceAsStream() to open files in the jar)

Comment: @ScottStanchfield That doesn't really work.  There are many things that require references to full paths as strings.  getResourceAsStream is only useful once in a while.

Comment: I agree.  getResourceAsStream() doesn't help things like a SWT web browser, which I ran into today, as a matter of fact.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can be chosen when configuring the feature including the plugin. Go to the plugin list, select your plugin and check "Unpack the plug-in archive after installation".

Arguably, this property should be defined by the plugin itself. There's a bug report about that https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=157562

regards,
Vlad

Comment: This seems to no longer work. My plug-in code is packaged as a jar file even with this setting. I also tried "Eclipse-BundleShape: dir" in the plug-in manifest, and omitting that directive. The unpack setting in feature.xml is not respected when exporting a deployable feature from the UI.

Comment: It works properly. The plug-in I was building did not have the bin/ dir specified in build.properties

Comment: @MidnightJava: I wonder, why would `bin` dir in the `build.properties` file matter for the plug-in to be unpacked? Do you know this?

Answer (score 9):

You can set the Eclipse-BundleShape value in your MANIFEST.MF file to either jar (the default) or dir. If set to dir, it is deploy unpacked.

```
Eclipse-BundleShape: dir
```

http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2009/01/20/tip-eclipse-bundleshape